# Angular-fullstack grunt build control heroku deploy error

Tags: node.js, heroku, sass, angular-fullstack, grunt-build-control

I am trying to deploy [this repo](https://github.com/alanbuchanan/booktrades) to heroku using `grunt --force && grunt buildcontrol:heroku`. The app is set up on heroku and linked to mongolab, having used the commands specified in the angular-fullstack docs/ When the build get to the buildcontrol process, this is the error I get:

```
Running "buildcontrol:heroku" (buildcontrol) task

Fetching master history from heroku.
From https://git.heroku.com/bookswitch
 = [up to date]      master     -> heroku/master

Committing changes to master.
[master 5339797] Built booktrade-bootstrap from commit 55c9f02 on branch master
 3 files changed, 5 insertions(+), 8 deletions(-)
 delete mode 100644 public/app/595dd67a.app.css
 create mode 100644 public/app/e153b419.app.css

Pushing master to heroku
Warning: remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote: -----> Using set buildpack heroku/nodejs
remote: -----> Node.js app detected
remote:
remote: -----> Creating runtime environment
remote:
remote:        NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
remote:        NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=true
remote:        NODE_ENV=production
remote:        NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
remote:
remote: -----> Installing binaries
remote:        engines.node (package.json):  5.0.0
remote:        engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)
remote:
remote:        Downloading and installing node 5.0.0...
remote:        Using default npm version: 3.3.6
remote:
remote: -----> Restoring cache
remote:        Loading 2 from cacheDirectories (default):
remote:        - node_modules
remote:        - bower_components (not cached - skipping)
remote:
remote: -----> Building dependencies
remote:        Pruning any extraneous modules
remote:        Installing node modules (package.json)
remote:
remote:        > bson-ext@0.1.13 install /tmp/build_1bb935a3d7064ef33cf450c77e2ba1a3/node_modules/bson-ext
remote:        > (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)
remote:
remote:        make: Entering directory `/tmp/build_1bb935a3d7064ef33cf450c77e2ba1a3/node_modules/bson-ext/build'
remote:        CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bson/ext/bson.o
remote:        SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/obj.target/bson.node
remote:        COPY Release/bson.node
remote:        make: Leaving directory `/tmp/build_1bb935a3d7064ef33cf450c77e2ba1a3/node_modules/bson-ext/build'
remote:
remote:        > kerberos@0.0.17 install /tmp/build_1bb935a3d7064ef33cf450c77e2ba1a3/node_modules/kerberos
remote:        > (node-gyp rebuild) || (exit 0)
remote:
remote:        make: Entering directory `/tmp/build_1bb935a3d7064ef33cf450c77e2ba1a3/node_modules/kerberos/build'
remote:        CXX(target) Release/obj.target/kerberos/lib/kerberos.o
remote:        CXX(target) Release/obj.target/kerberos/lib/worker.o
remote:        CC(target) Release/obj.target/kerberos/lib/kerberosgss.o
remote:        ../lib/kerberosgss.c:36:0: warning: ignoring #pragma clang diagnostic [-Wunknown-pragmas]
remote:        #pragma clang diagnostic push
remote:        ^
remote:        ../lib/kerberosgss.c:37:0: warning: ignoring #pragma clang diagnostic [-Wunknown-pragmas]
remote:        #pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wdeprecated-declarations"
remote:        ^
remote:        ../lib/kerberosgss.c: In function ‘authenticate_gss_client_wrap’:
remote:        ../lib/kerberosgss.c:362:19: warning: variable ‘server_conf_flags’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
remote:        char buf[4096], server_conf_flags;
remote:        ^
remote:        ../lib/kerberosgss.c: At top level:
remote:        ../lib/kerberosgss.c:930:0: warning: ignoring #pragma clang diagnostic [-Wunknown-pragmas]
remote:        #pragma clang diagnostic pop
remote:        ^
remote:        CC(target) Release/obj.target/kerberos/lib/base64.o
remote:        CXX(target) Release/obj.target/kerberos/lib/kerberos_context.o
remote:        SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/obj.target/kerberos.node
remote:        COPY Release/kerberos.node
remote:        make: Leaving directory `/tmp/build_1bb935a3d7064ef33cf450c77e2ba1a3/node_modules/kerberos/build'
remote:        booktrade-bootstrap@0.0.0 /tmp/build_1bb935a3d7064ef33cf450c77e2ba1a3
remote:        └── (empty)
remote:
remote:        npm ERR! code 1
remote:
remote: -----> Build failed
remote:
remote:        We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
remote:        https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys
remote:
remote:        If you're stuck, please submit a ticket so we can help:
remote:        https://help.heroku.com/
remote:
remote:        Love,
remote:        Heroku
remote:
remote:
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app
remote:
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !   Push rejected to bookswitch.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/bookswitch.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/bookswitch.git'
 Use --force to continue.
```

Part of me thinks this may be to do with SCSS, seeing as it has been giving me some run errors, and also it looks like it [partially deployed, but with a big fat SCSS error at the top](http://bookswitch.herokuapp.com/login).